# Why does referencing an object create an other instance of Excel?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have this code in PowerPoint that references an open excel workbook, but every time I set a PPT-Chart datasheet to be equal some range in the workbook, another instance of excel appears.  Does anyone know why this happens?

Could I be calling the subroutine inefficiently or am I not handling instances/Objects correctly?

```
    Sub Main()
    Dim xlWorkBook As Object
    Dim Template As String
    Dim lDate As String
    Dim company As String
    Dim Period as String

    'This is the excel data file
    path2 = "T:\User\Distributor\Distributor Test.xlsm" ' for testing only
    'This is the template file
    Template = ActivePresentation.FullName

    Set xlWorkBook = GetObject(path2)  'gets the excel object
    company = xlWorkBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value2
    Period = Left(xlWorkBook.Sheets(1).Range("A2").Value2, 2)
    lDate = Trim(xlWorkBook.Sheets(1).Range("A3").Value2)

    Call Slide_3(xlWorkBook, company, lDate, Period, Template)

 End Sub

Sub Slide_3(xlWorkBook, company, lDate, Period, Template)

            For Each oSH In Presentations(Template).Slides(3).Shapes
                Select Case oSH.Name
                    Case "DOLLARS_3"
                        With oSH.Chart.ChartData
                            'this updates the values in the datasheet and is the line that causes the new instance of excel.
                            .Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:B8").Value2 = xlWorkBook.Sheets(48).Range("A2:B8").Value
                        End With
                End Select
            Next oSH
        End Sub
```

Comment: Because *somewhere else* you have a section code that creates a new instance of excel instead of using the existing one.  (I can tell there's more since this obviously isn't a complete runnable code section (as per "[mcve]").

Comment: FWIW a file name with *two consecutive spaces*, and a trailing one before the file extension, is plain evil IMO ;-)

Comment: In fact, this code doesn't run at all, there are a few problems. (which became more clear simply by fixing your indentation.)  For example, you can't go ` Set xlWorkBook `.  Also you've included 1¼, procedures.  Please [edit] to provide a minimal/complete/verifiable example of your code as per "[mcve]".

Comment: Mathieu Guindon, I don't set the file name.

Comment: I meant that to be nothing more than a funny observation... that said I second @ashleedawg, you'll need a proper MCVE here.

Comment: This is a MVCE.

Comment: It might be now that you edited it. I'm just trying to get it going.  It's a good idea to include **`Option Explicit`** at the top of every module to "force" you to declare all your variable, use objects & properties properly, etc

Comment: .Workbook seems weird

Comment: .Workbook is how chart data is referenced in 2016 PPT.

Comment: Thanks mooseman for clarifying.

Comment: I changed the slide3 subrountine to Sub Slide_3(ByRef xlWorkBook, company, lDate, Period, Template).  While it seems stable, it still creates the Excel instance.